# Versioning an unversioned grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I'm working on a Rails app that uses `grape` for its API. Currently, there's a single version of the API that is mounted in the root folder (not `v1`, as I would like), and I need to start creating `v2`. The current version is mounted as follows:

`/app/api/api.rb`:

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    logger Rails.logger

    mount API::Things         => '/things'
end
```

and then I have `/app/api/api/things.rb` with something like:

```
module API
  class Things < Grape::API
    get '/' do
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, the API is mounted in `/api/things` with a hardcoded path. I need to:

- Make this API the `v1` without changing its path.
- Create a `v2` path.

So, I changed `api.rb` to be:

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    mount API::V1::Base
    mount API::V2::Base
  end
end
```

and created `api/api/v1/base.rb` as follows:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Base < Grape::API
      version 'v1', using: :accept_version_header

      mount API::Things         => '/things'
    end
  end
end
```

and then the same for `v2`:

```
module API
  module V2
    class Base < Grape::API
      version 'v2'

      mount API::V2::Things         => '/things'
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that `/things` does not inherit the `/v2` path component as I would expect. Therefore, since `v1` is mounted in `/things`, `v2` fails to mount there.

If I write `v2` to use `resources` instead of paths as `v1` is, it works, but I'd like to keep the mounts as is, to make `v2` consistent with `v1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misspelled v2, not writing the right quote -> you have 'v2`, not 'v2'...

It might also be cased by 'mount API::Things' as you might want to omit `API::` and write 'mount Things'

Comment: It's only misspelled here (just fixed it). The actual code is fine.

Comment: Yes. Same issue. It seems that for `v2` it's creating the route `/things/v2` instead of `/v2/things`.